# Simultaneous change of table cell values in tables on different pptx slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I got two (or more) same tables on two (or more) different PowerPoint slides, one table per slide.

I need to update the respective cell in all tables whenever I modify this cell on just one of them.

I have been trying to access the cell value and store it as a variable using pptx package.

The only thing I could do is InputBox() but it is not convenient.

Comment: Please, provide some code of what you have tried, even if it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PowerPoint lacks bookmarks and has only a few fields, you'll have to specify the read and write locations the long way. Keep an eye out for tables with merged or split cells, those can pose an addressing problem.

```
Sub UpdateTableCell()
  Dim CellContent$
  CellContent$ = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Table.Rows(2).Cells(2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
  ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).Table.Rows(3).Cells(4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CellContent$
End Sub
```

You'll probably find this more convenient to use if you add it to the Quick Access Toolbar. If the icon is in the 5th position on the QAT, you can run it with Alt + 5 for a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked just the way I wanted it to